# Prove: for $\alpha \in \mathbb C^n$, there exists $u\in C, |u|=1, \beta \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $\alpha=u\beta$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb C^n$ with component $\alpha_i, i=1,2,\dots,n$, such that $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\right|=\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\alpha_i\right|$. Show that there exists $u \in \mathbb C$ and $\beta \in \mathbb R^n$ with component $\beta_i, i=1,2,\dots,n$ such that:
$$
|u|=1, 
\forall i \in\{1,2, \cdots, n\}, \beta_i \geq 0 \text{ and } 
\alpha=u\beta
$$
Any help is eally appreciated ! In the case of $n=1$, it's clear but I can't find the general case !

Answer (score -1):

First, we prove for two number case, suppose $a_1=r_1 e^{i\theta_1}, a_2=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ are two complex numbers. Note if either one of them is zero, then it automatically hold, so we assume both of them are non-zero, we get

$$|a_1+a_2|=|a_1|+|a_2|\Rightarrow|r_1+r_2e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}|=r_1+r_2$$

Since we use the principle branch for the argument angles, then we get

$$\theta_1=\theta_2$$

hence,

$$\exists u=e^{i\theta_1}, \exists\beta=(r_1,r_2),~~ s.t.~ ~(a_1, a_2)=u\beta$$

Next, you can use induction to show all the components are aligned at the same argument angle $\theta_1$.

Can you proceed from here?